# Merge few lists into dictionary

Tags: ios, swift

I have 3 lists:

```
a = ["John", "Archie", "Levi"]
b = ["13", "20"]
c = ["m", "m", "m", "m"]
```

I want to merge this into one list with dictionaries:

```
    result = [
{"name": "John", "age": "13", "gender": "m"},
{"name": "Archie", "age": "20", "gender": "m"},
{"name": "Levi", "age": "", "gender": "m"},
{"name": "", "age": "", "gender": "m"},
    ]
```

Comment: you logic makes no sense. How are you going to decide who will be 20 years old

Comment: @LeoDabus makes sense to me. OP just uses the order of the array to determine. e.g `{name: a0, age: b0, gender: c0}, {name: a1, age: b1, gender: c1} ... `

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try like this:

```
let a = ["John", "Archie", "Levi"]
let b = ["13", "20"]
let c = ["m", "m", "m", "m"]


var dicArray:[[String:String]] = []

for index in 0..<max(a.count,b.count,c.count) {
    dicArray.append([:])
    dicArray[index]["name"] = index < a.count ? a[index] : ""
    dicArray[index]["age"] = index < b.count ? b[index] : ""
    dicArray[index]["gender"] = index < c.count ? c[index] : ""
}

dicArray  // [["gender": "m", "age": "13", "name": "John"], ["gender": "m", "age": "20", "name": "Archie"], ["gender": "m", "age": "", "name": "Levi"], ["gender": "m", "age": "", "name": ""]]
```

Answer (score 4):

Ok, this is pretty normal computer science problem. Here is an outline of how to go about solving it:

1. First, identify the inputs and the desired outputs. You've done that.
2. Note any edge cases you need to handle
3. Next, map out the logic flow using pseudo-code.
4. Convert from pseudo-code to real code.
5. Test and debug.

For step 2, your data suggests that you want to handle cases where you have different numbers of elements in each source array. it looks like you want to create a dictionary for all the 0 elements in each array, then a dictionary for the 1 elements, etc. When you run out of elements for a given array, it looks like you want to skip that key in your resulting dictionary entry.

Now to pseudo-code:

```
Find the array with the maximum number of elements. Make this your output_count (the number of items in your output array.)
Create an output array large enough for output_count entries.
Loop from 0 to output_count - 1.
  create a dictionary variable
    for each input array, if there are enough elements, add a key/value pair 
    for that array's key and the value at the current index. Otherwise skip 
    that key.
  add the new dictionary to the end of your output array.
```

That should be enough to get you started. Now see if you can convert that pseudo-code to actual code, test it, and debug it. Report back here with your actual code, and feel free to ask for help if you get stuck getting your code working.

Answer (score 2):

Here is my take.  I first create the array, and then use `enumerate()` and `forEach` to process each array and add them to the array of dictionaries:

```
let a = ["John", "Archie", "Levi"]
let b = ["13", "20"]
let c = ["m", "m", "m", "m"]

let count = max(a.count, b.count, c.count)

var result = Array(count: count, repeatedValue: ["name":"", "age":"", "gender":""])

a.enumerate().forEach { idx, val in result[idx]["name"] = val }
b.enumerate().forEach { idx, val in result[idx]["age"] = val }
c.enumerate().forEach { idx, val in result[idx]["gender"] = val }

print(result)
```

> [["gender": "m", "age": "13", "name": "John"], ["gender": "m", "age":
>   "20", "name": "Archie"], ["gender": "m", "age": "", "name": "Levi"],
>   ["gender": "m", "age": "", "name": ""]]

Answer (score 2):

This should do the job

```
let maxLength = max(a.count, b.count, c.count)
let paddedA = a + [String](count: maxLength-a.count, repeatedValue: "")
let paddedB = b + [String](count: maxLength-b.count, repeatedValue: "")
let paddedC = c + [String](count: maxLength-c.count, repeatedValue: "")

let res = zip(paddedA, zip(paddedB, paddedC)).map {
    ["name": $0.0, "age": $0.1.0, "gender": $0.1.1]
}
```

Output

```
[["gender": "m", "age": "13", "name": "John"], ["gender": "m", "age": "20", "name": "Archie"], ["gender": "m", "age": "", "name": "Levi"], ["gender": "m", "age": "", "name": ""]]
```

Comment: Elegant use of Swift, but this seems like a "give a man a fish" moment. With beginner questions like this I think providing code is actually counterproductive. I opted to explain *how* to solve the problem rather than giving a ready-made solution.

Comment: Hi @DuncanC, you provided a very detailed answer! I think all the answers in this page will be useful not only for the OP but for future readers as well. About me, I just provided the Functional Programming point of view :)

Comment: but if i will have more then 3 arrays ? then what to do? zip(zip(zip))) ?

Comment: Write code to handle the number of arrays that you have? e.g. `zip(a,zip(b,zip(c,d)))` or `zip(a,zip(b,zip(c,zip(d,e))))`. And update the max statements, and the padding, and the dictionary building, etc.

Comment: @Arti: your question begins with `I have 3 lists:` so I provided you the solution for 3 arrays. However if you want to add more arrays you can recursively add more `zip` calls.